# LibreOffice Impress: master slide font size not respected?

Tags: libreoffice, libreoffice-impress

I am trying to create a default master slide in LibreOffice Impress, where I want to set color/font size of the title and of the first level list. This works for the title, as well as for the color of the first level list, but not for the font?

Is that a bug (using LO 7.5.6.2), expected behavior, or am I doing something wrong?

##### Steps:

1. Create new document
2. Go to `View` -> `Master Slide`
3. Edit the master slide, change font and color of title (`Click to edit the title text format`) and list (`Click to edit the outline text format`).
4. Go to `View` -> `Normal`
5. Create a new slide, use layout `Title, Content`

See below how the master slide font is not respected by the slide?

##### Master slide

[image]

##### Normal slide

[image]